# Django csv HttpResponse working locally broken in production

Tags: python, django, csv, azure

I have a django view which allows users export a csv based on a date selection. Locally this feature works fine.

I have the web app hosted on Azure.

In Azure I'm getting a 404 (not found) error on the csv response URL.
My guess is I'll need to change something in settings.py for production or in Azure to allow the csv download.

The view code:

```
    def report(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
           ...
         do some stuff
           ...

       else:          
            if 'emp-csv' in request.GET:
            # data from date selection
            data = request.GET['data']
            # Convert string to list
            cleandata = ast.literal_eval(data)
            # creating csv response
            response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='hours_report.csv'"
            # Write data to csv file and return
            fieldnames = ['Supervisor', 'EmployeeID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'NT', 'OT', 'OT2', 'Project', 'Client', 'date']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=fieldnames, dialect='excel', )
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(cleandata)

            return response
```

The URL code:

```
url(r'employees/report/export', hours_views.report, name="export_csv"),
```

The URL generated in Azure:

https://xyzxyz.azurewebsites.net/employees/report/export?csrfmiddlewaretoken=(..CSRF_TOKEN)&data=(...DATA)

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*"
         modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>

  <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\Python27\python.exe"
 arguments="run_waitress_server.py" requestTimeout="00:04:00" 
  startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true">
   <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
   </environmentVariables>
  </httpPlatform>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Waitress.py file:

```
import os
from waitress import serve
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "isi_django.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
serve(application, host="0.0.0.0", port=os.environ["PORT"], url_scheme='https')
```

Comment: 404 seems not an error in view. It depends on how you integrate webserver with django. post you webserver config and full view code of `report`

Comment: I edited above to include the web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this thanks to some help from one of the users in the Django/django gitter channel (shout out to @MBijman).

Passing data for the csv export in the URL was causing the issue.
I changed the view code to set a cookie value to the data:

```
request.session['emp-data'] = emp_data
```

Then I seperated the csv export into a new view:

```
@login_required
def csv_report(request):
# If request is for Excel report
if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'emp-csv' in request.GET:
        # data from date selection
        data = request.session['emp-data']
        # creating csv response
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='hours_report.csv'"
        # Write data to csv file and return
        fieldnames = ['Supervisor', 'EmployeeID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'NT', 'OT', 'OT2', 'Project', 'Client',
                  'date']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=fieldnames, dialect='excel', )
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

        return response
```